# What causes the navigationBar to turn white hazy color after setting both barItem properties?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I was working on building out a navigation controller and the nav bar all of a sudden added this white hazy color to the nav bar and I don't know what property that is.  I've tried turning translucent off and also setting the background color however the new red background color appears behind the white hazy color.  What causes this white hazy color and how do I remove it?

Here is my code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnCancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed)];
    self.navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnCancel;

    UIBarButtonItem *btnSave = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnSave;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I placed code inside of view will appear that set an integer variable.  As I understand it view did load should come before view will appear so I don't understand why this problem is happening but it was the issue.